# Is the number of color attachments bounded by API

Tags: opengl, api-design

The OpenGL specification requires that a framebuffer supports at least 8 color attachments. Now, OpenGL uses compile-time constants (at least on my system), for stuff like `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` and `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` attachment follows 32 units after `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. Doesn't this mean that regardless of how beefy the hardware is, it will never be possible to use more than 32 color attachments? To clarify, this compiles perfectly with GLEW on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
static_assert(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 32==GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,"");
```

and since it is static_assert, this would be true for any hardware configuration (unless the driver installer modify the header files, which would result in non-portable binaries). Wouldn't separate functions for different attachment classes would have been better as it removes the possibility of colliding constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to note the difference in spec language. `glActiveTexture` says this about its parameter:

> An INVALID_ENUM error is generated if an invalid texture is specified.
>   *texture* is a symbolic constant of the form TEXTURE*i*, indicating that texture unit *i* is to be modified. Each TEXTURE*i* adheres to TEXTURE*i* = TEXTURE0 + *i*, where *i* is in the range zero to k−1, and k is the value of MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS

This text explicitly allows you to compute the enum value, explaining exactly how to do so and what the limits are.

Compare this to what it says about `glFramebufferTexture`:

> An INVALID_ENUM error is generated if *attachment* is not one of the attachments in table 9.2, and *attachment* is not COLOR_ATTACHMENT*m* where *m* is greater than or equal to the value of MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS.

It looks similar. But note that it doesn't have the language about the *value* of those enumerators. There's nothing in that description about COLOR_ATTACHMENT*m* = COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + *m*.

As such, it is illegal to use any value other than those specific enums. Now yes, the spec does guarantee *elsewhere* that COLOR_ATTACHMENT*m* = COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + *m*. But because the guarantee isn't in that section, that section explicitly prohibits the use of any value other than an actual enumerator. Regardless of how you compute it, the result must be an actual enumerator.

So to answer your question, at present, there are only 32 color attachment enumerators. Therefore, MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENT has an effective maximum value of 32.

Comment: *There's nothing about COLOR_ATTACHMENTm = COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + m.* Uhm... no, there is. Check the 4.5 spec, page 288, §9.2: *Each `COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` adheres to `COLOR_ATTACHMENTi = COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i`*

Comment: @peppe: True enough. But the function *itself* does not say that it can take values other than those enumerators. By contrast, `glActiveTexture` *explicitly* allows you to provide values that are not actual enumerators.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenGL 4.5 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf) states in Section 9.2:

> ... by the framebuffer attachment points named `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` through `COLOR_ATTACHMENTn`. Each `COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` adheres to `COLOR_ATTACHMENTi = COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i`

and as a footnote

> The header files define tokens `COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` for i in the range [0, 31]. Most implementations support fewer than 32 color attachments, and it is an INVALID_OPERATION error to pass an unsupported attachment name to a command accepting color attachment names.

My interpretation of this is, that it is (as long as the hardware supports it) perfectly fine to use `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 32` and so on to address more than 32 attachment points. So there is no real limitation of supported color attachments, just the constants are not defined directly. Why it was designed that way can only be answered by people from the khronos group.

Comment: My point is that GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 32==GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT

Comment: It's "more complicated". The values of these defines are specified by Khronos itself on many platforms, see `glext.h` [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) and the [Khronos API Implementers Guide](https://www.khronos.org/registry/implementers_guide.html) for a full reference. There *could* be more than 32 attachments in the future if the enumerators change (which is an ABI break, which noone ever wants). Is there however any need soon for more than 32 color attachments?