# Storing OpenGL color attachments in constexpr GLenum array

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl

I am using the following constexpr GLenum array to represent `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTx` (where x is an unsigned integer between 0 and 7):

```
constexpr std::array<GLenum, 8> opengl_color_attachment{GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT5, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT6, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT7};
```

This works fine for only the first eight available color attachments (which the OpenGL specification states to be the minimum). However, there is a possibility of more attachments, which is implementation defined. As the macro `GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS` represents the number of attachments available, I wanted to edit this constexpr array to include ALL available attachments to the limit, instead of the minimum of 8.

I created the following macro in an attempt to solve this issue myself:

```
#define OPENGL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT(x) GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT##x
```

Although I wanted to use this in a constexpr function to create the array in compile-time, it failed because preprocessor macros are obviously processed before compilation. Although the OpenGL standard guarantees that `GL_TEXTURE1 == GL_TEXTURE0 + 1`, I could not find such a reference for this macro, so I am unsure whether they are sequential in this case.

Is there a way for me to create the constexpr array fully from GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTx where x = GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS, with or without preprocessor macros?

Comment: Are the `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTx` values sequential?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo See my most recent edit: The OpenGL specification guarantees that GL_TEXTUREx values are sequential, but I am not able to find reference to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTx, so I would expect it be implementation-defined. Although I may be wrong.

Comment: @Harrand: "*I wanted to edit this constexpr array to include ALL available attachments to the limit, instead of the minimum of 8.*" Since the actual limit is implementation defined, that's *impossible* for anything that you need to be a compile-time defined quantity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been established, [you cannot effectively use more than 32 attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343872/is-the-number-of-color-attachments-bounded-by-api/42350338#42350338), because `glFramebufferTexture` doesn't accept anything except an enumerator. `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 32` just so happens to be equal to `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`, so obviously the implementation cannot tell the difference between using a texture as the 33rd color attachment and as a depth attachment. It will assume the latter.

So really, just make an array of 32 attachments and move on. Or just use `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i`, where `i` is less than 32. The enumerators in the specification are indeed sequential; it's just that, unlike texture unit enums, nobody left any space for more than 32. You can even make a `constexpr` function to generate such values if you want.

Comment: Good call. Seems like a better option to me to create the constexpr array that way as opposed to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 upto 32, so that's what I will do.